# I am trying to access Same log file in different methods I am getting errors

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a log file and write to the file and I am using same file in different methods and I am getting an error. Please correct me if I am doing wrong.

```
foreach (var corporationObj in corporations)
{
    // Log which corporation it is currenlty doing
    _keepItDry.Log("Started Data Summarisation for corporation: @" + corporationObj.Description, w);
    // Pass the coporationId and call method to DoProductStatsForCorporation and also pass the log file to continue our logging.
    w.Flush();
    // w.Close();
    w.Dispose();

    DoProductStatsForCorporation(corporationObj.Id, path);
}
```

Here's the listing for the method being called in the loop:

```
private void DoProductStatsForCorporation(int corporationId, string logFilePath)
{
    var corporationManufacturerRepository = new CorporationManufacturerRepository();
    var manufacturerRepository = new ManufacturerRepository();
    // Get brand sfor the coporationId passes
    var corporationManufacturers  = corporationManufacturerRepository.GetAllManufacturersForCorporation(corporationId);
    //check before process is used by another object
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(logFilePath);
    IsFileLocked(fileInfo);
    using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(logFilePath))
    {
        // If brands are existing for the corporation proceed.
        if (corporationManufacturers.Any())
        {
            // loop through each brand to processs
            foreach (var corporationManufacturer in corporationManufacturers)
            {
#region ProductStats
                // get the manufacturer row so that we can know more details about the manufacturer
                var manufacturer =  manufacturerRepository.GetManufacturer(corporationManufacturer.ManufacturerId);
                // Get the countries for the manufacturer

                _keepItDry.Log("Started Doing data summarisation for Brand: @ " + manufacturer.Description, w);
                // this is common method so extracted to reuse it.
                // we need to clos ethe file as we are sending to another function.
                w.Flush();
                w.Dispose();

                DoProductStatsForBrand(manufacturer, logFilePath);

#endregion ProductStats

                _keepItDry.AddTolistBox(DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ": Ended Summarizing data for " + manufacturer.Description, _listBoxLog);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _keepItDry.Log(" No Brands are there for the selected Corporation Please check if Brands are mapped for this Corporation ? : @ ", w);
            _keepItDry.AddTolistBox(DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "  : No Brands are there for the selected Corporation Please check if Brands are mapped for this Corporation ", _listBoxLog);
        }

        //  w.Flush();
        // w.Dispose();
    }    
    //  GC.Collect();
}
```

After coming for next corporation Id I am getting "current file is closed".

Comment: What exception are you receiving?

Comment: @M.Babcock The process cannot access the file 'd:\DataSummarisationLogfiles\2013-09-17\DataSummarisation2013-09-17 01-41-52-AM' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: if I do w.Close() then I am getting when it comes to second loop it is saying Cannot write to a closed TextWriter.

Comment: The issue is likely that the file isn't being opened for shared writes, but your code is a bit to messy to be able to tell for sure.

Answer (score 1):

First you have

```
using (StreamWriter w ...
```

Then inside you have

```
`foreach`  loop
```

Inside which you have

```
w.Flush();
w.Dispose();
```

You just disposed your object - how is it going to work?
If you have 2 `corporationManufacturers`, you will go one loop and then error...

`using` is your disposing mechanism. You just need a flag inside to verify that the block completed well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StreamWriter` to write a file.
after writing the file dispose the file.

```
streamWriter.Flush();
streamWriter.Close();
```

`Close()` calls the `Dispose()` method also.